# How to return the middle node of a linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I'm confused about how the while loop condition works in a linked list when checking for the middle node of a linked list

This is the correct code that I have for finding the middle node of a linked list

```py
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class linkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, data):
        node = Node(data)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = node
        temp = self.head
        while temp.next:
            temp = temp.next
        temp.next = node

    def middle(self):
        first = self.head
        second = self.head
        while second and second.next:
            second = second.next.next
            first = first.next
        print(first.data)
```

If I change the while loop to

```py
while second:
```

or

```py
while second.next:
```

I receive an error that says

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next' on line 24`

I'm just wondering why it's important to have both `second` and `second.next`

Comment: because only if `second` has a valid value you can call `second.next` and likewise only if you have a valid `second.next` you can call `second.next.next`

Comment: Check my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

The solution works by using two pointers. First one takes 1 step at a time and second 2 steps at a time. However, in taking 2 steps there are two things to verify:

1. There is a next step that is valid
2. There is a step after the next step mentioned above

If you skip one check it will enter the loop but at the boundary condition it not find the next. To illustrate: If there are 4 nodes and you only check for `second.next` at the 3nd node you'll have `second.next` as valid and you'll enter the `while` loop but inside that you are directly accessing `second.next.next`

F,S
|
1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> None

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your append method doesn't work, and gets stuck in an infinite while loop, since you don't exit out of append on adding the first element. The correct version is

```
def append(self, data):
    node = Node(data)
    if self.head == None:
        self.head = node
        return
    else:
        temp = self.head
        while temp.next:
            temp = temp.next
        temp.next = node
```

As to your other question, we want to find the middle of the loop for both even and odd lists, the `second.next` covers the odd list case, and the `second` covers the even list case, since either the 2nd pointer will point to null, or it will be null itself, and if you use only one of them, you will get the error you described it, hence you need to have both conditions in the while loop